# How to use CSS to make images in multiple li of one ul align by bottom edge?

Tags: html, css

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/MhcTz/

- pictures are random selected by google image search, just for demo the size difference)
- updated to quite close the result wanted, just need make the whole ul to center.

I'm looking for a pure CSS solution, which means I may keep the HTML clean instead of embedding a div in another div just for visual effects.

Result expected:

```
[img1]       [img2]      [img3]
--------------------------------
            [notes1]    [notes2]
```

Current I got:

```
--------------------------------
[img1]       [img2]      [img3]
            [notes1]    [notes2]
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="subject-contents">
   <li> <img src="images/img1.png"> </li>
   <li>
        <img src="images/img2.png">
        <p>notes...</p>
   </li>
   <li>
        <img src="images/img3.png">
        <p>notes...</p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.subject-contents {
    /* it is horizontal but valign top */
    list-style-type: none;
    width:75%;
    overflow:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 64pt;
    background: url(../images/bottom_boarder.png) center bottom no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
}

ul.subject-contents li {
    float:left;
}

ul.subject-contents li img+p{
   /* ?? */
}

ul.subject-contents li:last-child(){
   float:clear;
}
```

Comment: Can you just setup a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Are your images all the same height?

Comment: No, these image has different height.

Comment: So your border will line up with the bottom edge of the tallest image?

Comment: And your notes, are they single line or can they wrap onto two lines?

Comment: I can limit the notes be single line. If it is possible for multiple lines then it is perfect.

Comment: Actually, this would be trivial using table-cells.

Comment: Any comments on my updated solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two prototypes of something that might work.

### Using Floats

Try the following CSS:

```
ul.subject-contents {
    /* it is horizontal but valign top */
    list-style-type: none;
    width:75%;
    overflow:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 64pt;
    XXXX background: url(../images/bottom_boarder.png) center bottom no-repeat;
    XXXX text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
    height: 120px;
}
ul.subject-contents:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted gray;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.subject-contents li {
    float:left;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
}
ul.subject-contents li img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
ul.subject-contents li p {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    width: inherit; /* you may need to set this */
    background-color: beige;
}
ul.subject-contents li:last-child(){
   float:clear;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/2uc2h/

If you rely on floats, you need to set some heights and widths to get the effect that you want.

### Using Table-Cells

An easier way is to use `display: table-cells`, for example:

```
<div class="subject-contents">
    <div class="row-wrap r1">
        <p><img src="http://placehold.it/100x30"></p>
        <p><img src="http://placehold.it/100x50"></p>
        <p><img src="http://placehold.it/100x30"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="row-wrap r2">
        <p>notes...</p>
        <p>notes...</p>
        <p>notes that can wrap...</p>
    </div>
</div>

div.subject-contents {
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
div.row-wrap {
    display: table-row;
}
div.row-wrap p {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
}
div.row-wrap img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

See other demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/VtVuY/

Comment: 1. bottom edges of these images are in same line. 2. Yes, I can. But it is better not to.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks, it is quite close. The images are top align so far, I want them be bottom align.

Comment: Thanks, Marc! I'm not a fan of div indeed. I will try to adopt table-cell display into original html structure and confirm here if it works. PS, sorry for the later responding, I just had a long day.

Comment: Marc, table-cell does the trick well, only one side effect, the ul failed to align center. I updated my jsfiddle to current status.